# A question about the Riemann Roch space over a compact Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface, 
let $D$ be a divisor on $X$.

Consider the Riemann-Roch space $L(D)$.

Take some point $p \in X$ such that $p$ is not in $D$ (that is, the support of $p$ at $D$ is $0$).

Could it happen that $f(p) = 0$ for all $p \in L(D)$? 
I guess this means that $L(D) = L(D-p)$. Could this happen? Is there a name for such points $p$ and a characterization of them?

Comment: Let $X = \mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})$ and $D = 2[0]-[i/2]$. Then $L(D)= \{ f \in \mathbb{C}(X), div(f)+D \ge 0\}$ is of dimension $1$ generated by the Weierstrass function $ \wp(z)$ which has a double pole at $0$, and two simple zeros at $i/2$ and $1/2$.